# Backward difference and central difference in R

Tags: r, finite-difference

I know that in R `diff(x, lag = L, differences = K)` gives you the lag-`L` `K`-th order forward difference. But it only allows for positive lags, so only can give you the forward differences, not backward differences or central differences...

Is there an equivalent function to calculate the lag-`L` `K`-th order backward difference and central difference as well though (ideally allowing `x` to be either a vector or a matrix)? I searched CRAN and can't seem to find anything, but it would seem such a trivial thing that the function ought to exist already somewhere. Anybody any thoughts? `diff.zoo` allows for negative lags, so can give you negative differences, and by averaging the result of forward & negative differences one could manually get the central diffference. But that only works on `zoo` objects, not regular vectors or matrices. Anything that I missed? Or should I make my own function based on `diff.zoo`?

Comment: diff.zoo supports lags and higher orders. ?diff.zoo   filter in base of R can handle general linear filters and rollapply in zoo can handle general window operations.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thanks, but that only works on zoo objects, right, and not on regular vectors or matrices, which is what I am looking for...

Comment: zoo(x) will give you a zoo object so its pretty simple.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Fair enough, will do it like that then... Central difference is avg then of forward and backward difference, right?

Comment: You can use filter in base R or rollapply in zoo if you need something more complex.

Comment: Also I just checked and diff in base R does support lags and higher order differences so maybe that is sufficient for you.

Comment: Are the backward/central differences different from the lagged forward differences?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Yes, of course diff() in base R supports lags & higher order differences. But it only allows for positive lags, so only can give you the forward differences, not backward differences or central differences... Hence my question.. diff.zoo allows for negative lags, so can give you negative differences, and by averaging the result of forward & negative differences one could manually get the central diffference. But I felt it just ought to be the function that should already be out there somewhere, with argument lag, differences and type="forward", "backward" or "central".

Comment: See ?diff.zoo .  It indicates that lag= and differences= can both be negative.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Yes I know diff.zoo allows negative lag, base R diff not unfortunately. Still doesn't have the central difference though - one has to calculate that as the average of the forward & backward difference then...

Comment: Just use filter as I mentioned.  `stats::filter(x, c(1, -2, 1))`

Comment: @TomWenseleers I am facing the same problem as you. There is this blogpost showing some algorithms: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/08/numerical-differentiation-with-finite-differences-in-r/. There is also `pracma::fderiv()` Have you found a better alternative without using time series - related methods?

Comment: @Paul: no the only one I found was diff.zoo working on zoo objects, but didn't find anything working on regular vectors or matrices. If you do, please let me know! For me it would be preferable performance-wise... pracma::fderiv is for functions, so that's also not quite what I was looking for...